# java: cannot find symbol symbol: variable POST

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have below logic in my Java code

```
switch (method) {
    case POST:
        // Logic
        break;
    case PUT:
        // Logic
        break;
}
```

This logic is working when I'm using spring-web version as 5.3.22.
I'm getting below issue when I'm using spring-web version as 6.0.2.
Please suggest

[image]

Comment: is it giving issue for only POST keyword or something else , you can try with "POST"

Comment: @RaushanKumar It is giving error for GET, PUT also

Comment: can you please check import , with given snippet it's difficult to identify where is the issue

Comment: Please show more of the code.  Are you using an enumeration?  How are the variables defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that up to Spring version 5.3.x, `HttpMethod` used to be an `enum` (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.3.x/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/HttpMethod.java#L33):

> ```
> public enum HttpMethod {
> ```

But they changed in in Spring Version 6.x to a "normal" class (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/HttpMethod.java#L37):

> ```
> public final class HttpMethod implements Comparable<HttpMethod>, Serializable {
> ```

The reason for this [change](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/6e335e3a9ff7727dc42e790904ae98a6d0edb7b5) is given as

> **Refactor HTTP Method from Enum to Class**
>
> This commit refactors HttpMethod from a Java enum into a class. The
> underlying reason being that HTTP methods are not enumerable, but
> instead an open range and not limited to the predefined values in the
> specifications.

---

While you can use enum constants in a `switch` statement, you cannot use instances of normal classes.

Therefore if you want to use Spring version 6.x you must rewrite your`switch(method)` to an `if ()` - `else if ()` chain or use specific request mappings for the different methods.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer is really helpful for me. Rather than providing some fix details you have explained everything in detail.